# Word choice between us and each other

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, word-choice, prepositions

Hey I’ve got two sentences which sound almost the same to me

1. We have real intimacy between us.
2. We have real intimacy between each other.

Do they carry the  same meaning or are they grammatically incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

> We have real intimacy between us.

This makes more sense than:

> We have real intimacy between each other.

The latter not really making any sense, because "each other" implies a separation, when the intimacy is actually only in one place ("between us").

But to me neither sound idiomatic.

What you could say:

> There is real intimacy between us.
>
> We have real intimate feelings towards one other.
>
> We have a real intimate connection.
>
> We have real intimacy together.

Answer (score 0):

"We know each other" could be paraphrased "Each of us knows the other." "We respect each other" could similarly be paraphrased "Each of us respects the other."

But "We have a real intimacy between each other" could not be expressed "Each of us has a real intimacy between the other." I guess that this is because "between" involves the concept of a plurality, so that it is not possible for anything to exist between one person.

Anyhow, your first choice, "We have a real intimacy between us," is better in my opinion, although it also sounds casual to me. I think I would express the thought "There is a real intimacy between us," or "We share a real intimacy."